# C# While loop not working

Tags: c#, .net, while-loop

New programmer working on a little file mover. Not sure why my while statement is not working. I am trying to have the program check if the file exists in the directory and if so, `counter++` until it comes up with an original name e.g. 2018 Picture(45) and so on...

```
private void btnMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Personal Pictures & Videos\fromme";
    string destinationPath = @"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Personal Pictures & Videos\practicefolder";

    if (!Directory.Exists(destinationPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);
    }

    string[] sourcefiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
    //looks at each file with its path attached.
    int counter = 1;
    foreach (string sourcefile in sourcefiles)
    {

        if (sourcefile.EndsWith(".jpeg"))
        {
            string destFile = Path.Combine(destinationPath, "2018 Picture" + "(" + counter + ")" + ".jpeg");
            MessageBox.Show(destFile);
            while (Directory.Exists(destFile))
            {
                    counter++;
            }
            //renames and moves files from sourcePath to destinationPath
            File.Move(sourcefile, destFile);
```

Comment: You never update the `destFile` so if it exists then you've got an infinite loop.  A `do-while` loop would make more sense as you want to create `destFile` at least once and keep recreating it with a new counter if it already exists.

Comment: Why are you using `Directory.Exists` with a file? See: [File.Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: You haven't actually described how your code isn't working. You just said "not working." Describe what you want it to do *and* what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incrementing just the counter does not automatically update the file name, which you check to exist for the break condition of the loop.

```
while(File.Exists(destFile))
{
    counter++;
    destFile = Path.Combine(destinationPath, $"2018 Picture({ counter }).jpeg");
}
```

We have to update the file name with the incremented counter every time.

The $ syntax for string concatenation is optional but makes the file name composition clearer.

Furthermore, `Directory.Exists` does not work for files. If you pass a file name that exists, it will still return false, because it [checks for the directory flag](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,448) on the file system entry.

Comment: Thanks so much! I feel sorry to have missed the obvious lack of re-checking the path after increasing the counter. I also used $ as it does indeed look better. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I found several things to correct or improve.

```
private void btnMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Personal Pictures & Videos\fromme";
    string destinationPath = @"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Personal Pictures & Videos\practicefolder";

    //no need to check if the path exists. CreateDirectory() already does the right thing
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);   

    int counter = 0; 
    var sourcefiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourcePath, "*.jpeg");
    foreach (string sourcefile in sourcefiles)
    {            
        bool tryAgain = true;
        while (tryAgain)
        {
            try 
            {
                counter++;
                destFile = Path.Combine(destinationPath, $"2018 Picture ({ counter }).jpeg");
                File.Move(sourcefile, destFile);
                tryAgain = false;
                MessageBox.Show(destfile);
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {   //file I/O is one of the few places where exceptions might be okay for flow control
                tryAgain =  (counter < 10000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice addition using the file mask for the list of files.

Comment: I like the interpolated string in @dlatikay 's answer, too. I'm still not used to thinking about interpolation. I may steal just that one piece (with the comment here to give appropriate credit).

Comment: Hey, thanks for showing me another way of doing it! Many appreciations. I like how you used the try/catch.

Comment: Most of the time, try/catch is a **very bad** way to do flow control. Even here, it's not good. It just happens to be a little less bad in this case than the extra disk I/O you get from the extra `.Exists()` check.

Answer (score 1):

Put the your code creating the filename inside the loop and the File.Move outside of the loop.  You should also set an upper limit on "counter" so that you can't get stuck in an infinite loop.  Then only do the File.Move if you don't hit the limit.  Since you're going to be changing the name with every iteration, you should only display the messagebox after the new filename has been successfully found.

```
foreach (string sourcefile in sourcefiles)
    {
        if (sourcefile.EndsWith(".jpeg"))
        {
            bool bSuccess = true;
            string destFile = Path.Combine(destinationPath, "2018 Picture" + "(" + counter + ")" + ".jpeg");
            counter = 0;
            while (File.Exists(destFile))
            {
                destFile = Path.Combine(destinationPath, "2018 Picture" + "(" + counter + ")" + ".jpeg");
                counter++;
                if(counter>1000)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("'Too many tries.' or what ever message you want to use.");                        
                    bSuccess = false;;
                }
            }
            if(bSuccess)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(destFile);
                File.Move(sourcefile, destFile);
            }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for explaing! Yes I have deleted the messagebox now, I only put that there temporarily to help me debug.